# Spring Authorization Server: how to continue authorization after login

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am trying to integrate [Authorization Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server) into my app with form login. I'm using my own login page.
Samples suggest to use the following configuration:

```java
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
//...
        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) ->
                    exceptions
                         .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
//...
                )
```

Now when I try to authorize (`/oauth2/authorize?...`) I got redirection to my login page. If I logged in before I see OAuth consent page and able to submit consent. But 99% of times I see my `/login` page, able to log in and stuck here. How to continue to consent page there? Should I write my own logic for that?

Comment: I don't think I'm following the specific problem you're facing. The snippet above is simply lifted from the Getting Started example, so it's not clear what you've customized in your deployment that causes the flow not to work for you. Can you provide more details and/or the full configuration? I'm also not clear on what's meant by "able to log in and stuck here"

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg expected behavior: client (e.g. mobile app) requests authorization code and receive redirect to login page, it is opened in app's webview where I enter my credentials, then continue to consent page and then redirected to redirect_uri defined in authorization code request with the actual code. It works when I'm already authenticated and /login page is skipped, but it does not redirect to consent page if /login page is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue myself by removing custom `.successHandler(...)` from my custom  form login configuration. Default `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` correctly handle  all redirects as expected.